# Naming conventions for BOOL Obj-C 2 properties?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a readonly BOOL property. What is dominant naming pattern here?

Background: for plain old method declarations, the accepted pattern

```
- (BOOL)isEditable;
- (void)setEditable:(BOOL)flag;
```

In a @property world, that would typically be expressed as

```
@property(getter=isEditable) BOOL editable;
```

However, there are examples to the contrary. Such as in CalStore/CalCalendar.h

```
@property(readonly) BOOL isEditable;
```

(Is CalCalendar wrong here, or is that the also an acceptable naming pattern for read-only BOOL properties?)

I've got a controller which manages a view, which may or may not be resizable. The property is read only.

```
@property(readonly) BOOL viewIsResizable;
@property(readonly) BOOL isViewResizable;
@property(readonly, getter=isViewResizable) BOOL viewResizable;
```

Which pattern is most natural or Cocoa-like?

Comment: It seems very awkward to me to have to write calendar.isEditable as opposed to calendar.editable. I think your third option is the most "Cocoa-like" and natural. It's mainly a matter of opinion, but that would be my preference since it's most consistent with the rest of Cocoa.

Comment: It's not a matter of opinion, it's a matter of being correct. That being said, Alex is definitely right: the third one is the way to go.

Comment: Alex seems to contradict himself - isn't the 3rd answer the one that would result in "calendar.isEditable" which is the one referred to as "awkward"

Comment: Rhubarb: No; the third answer is `@property(readonly, getter=isViewResizable) BOOL viewResizable;`.

Answer (score 29):

quoted from [ADC](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282)

> If the attribute is expressed as an
>   adjective, the format is:
>
> ```
> - (void)setAdjective:(BOOL)flag;
> - (BOOL)isAdjective;
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> - (void)setEditable:(BOOL)flag;
> - (BOOL)isEditable;
> ```
>
> If the attribute is expressed as a verb, the format is:
>
> ```
> - (void)setVerbObject:(BOOL)flag; 
> - (BOOL)verbObject;
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> - (void)setShowsAlpha:(BOOL)flag;
> - (BOOL)showsAlpha;
> ```
>
> The verb should be in the simple present tense.

|K<

Comment: What kent said; your property should be named "resizable" or "viewResizable" and should declare getter=isViewResizable.

Comment: A better link to the ADC would be the page on properties rather than accessors - since it shows how to declare this as a property https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-BAJGIIJE

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it really matters, since KVO will look at both `is<Key>` and `<Key>`.

Looking at the iPhone classes, the most common pattern I've seen is:

> @property(nonatomic, getter=isHidden) BOOL hidden;

This let's you access the property in these ways:

```
obj.hidden = YES; // (1)
BOOL hidden = obj.hidden; // (2)
BOOL hidden = [obj isHidden]; // (3)
```

But not:

```
BOOL hidden = obj.isHidden; // (4)
```

CalStore does not follow that convention. You would be have to use line 4 instead of line 2.

Comment: The interesting difference here (whether it is significant is another matter) is that in CalStore the property is read-only.

obj.hidden = YES reads naturally, whereas obj.isHidden = YES is less so.

But in the read-only case, you are never assigning the state, only querying it.

Answer (score 4):

You'd want to use the one that works with KVO, KVC and bindings etc.

I remember reading that in the Docs that KVO et al. will look for `is<key>`, `set<key>` as well as `get<key>` and many others like `countOf<key>`

The [KVC Compliance Checklist](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Compliant.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172) explains it much better than I could ever do.

Answer (score 3):

The CalStore example seems to be violating the convention. I'd stick to where the property name, as opposed to the method name, doesn't have an "is" in it.

Answer (score -2):

The convention is definitely to do `is...` for BOOL getters. The reason you see the property set like that in CalStore is most likely because it's read-only and written that way for basic readability of the header file, since:

```
@property(readonly) isEditable;
```

is generally easier to read than:

```
@property(readonly, getter=isEditable) editable;
```

For the first type of property, in your implementation you could do either of:

```
@synthesize isEditable = editable;
```

or simply define the accessor:

```
- (BOOL)isEditable(void) { return editable; }
```

This leaves the interface file (the header) more easily readable by a potential user.

Comment: In cases 2 and 3, the getter is going to be named isViewResizable. It is just a matter of what the property is named.

[controller isViewResizable];

but

controller.isViewResizable or controller.viewResizable

The latter reads funny, but is consistent with

[button isEditable] -> button.editable

(which itself is inconsistent with CalCalendar.)

Comment: @property(readonly) isEditable; is not equivalent to @property(readonly, getter=isEditable) editable; because in the former case the property is accessed with foo.isEditable and in the latter with foo.editable. It's got nothing to do with header readability, it's simply wrong. Changing the ivar back to editable using the synthesise statement won't change the property name.

Comment: @NickLockwood He was asking about convention and some people prefer to access their read-only properties via 'is' style getters. You can absolutely access the `editable` property in the second example as `foo.isEditable`. Obviously, you can _only_ access it this way in the first style. Synthesizing to the ivar `editable` wasn't an attempt to change the property name... it's obviously `isEditable` it was to change the ivar so that code setting it in the actual class still follows setter conventions. Either way, I personally would only ever use the second.

Comment: Fair enough - your answer seemed a little misleading as it implies that 1) is a just a more readable way of writing 2), as opposed to generating a different method name.