# Custom accessors and the "=" in the properties?

Tags: objective-c, accessor

Can you tell me the meaning of those custom accessors :

why would you add this info next to the setter :

```
@property (assign,getter=isSelected) BOOL selected;
```

and about the setter,

```
@property (copy,setter=setDefaultTitle:) NSString* title;
```

is this the same as writing @synthesize title=defaultTitle ?

Thanks

Comment: No, because you are changing the **setter** method alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@property (assign,getter=isSelected) BOOL selected;
```

in your header file, specifies that you want to other classes to be able to use `myObject.isSelected` to access this property.  You're defining this name in the public interface to your class.

```
@synthesize title = defaultTitle;
```

in your implementation file, specifies that you have defined a property named `title` for other classes to use, but internally to your class you want to actually use the name `defaultTitle`. This is normally done when you have declared your own private instance variable named `defaultTitle` which you don't want people modifying directly.

Comment: thanks, in your example, defaultTitle is not supposed to be modified, but can we do "myClass.title = smthg" will this work? what's the point the make the variable defaultTitle private, and let the property title public?

Comment: The point is to force the use of the getter and setter methods, to make sure that code runs when the value is to be changed. This way, other classes can use the property, but they cannot simply make changes to the value without going through the getter or setter.

Answer (score 1):

`@property (assign,getter=isSelected) BOOL selected;`

must specify the getter to conform to naming convention. See Apple's manual citation:

> Typically you should specify accessor method names that are key-value
>   coding compliant (see Key-Value Coding Programming Guide)—a common
>   reason for using the getter decorator is to adhere to the
>   isPropertyName convention for Boolean values.

`@property (copy,setter=setDefaultTitle:) NSString* title;`
It would be the same if you also specify the getter. You have to however use the `@synthesize title = defaultTitle;` to generate the proper method names for your getter/setter methods.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [FAQ]. In particular, [do not use a signature](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) (especially one that contains links, which are likely to be perceived as spam). If you want your name to appear at the bottom of your post, change your username in your profile.

Comment: @user929170 : thanks, so it is exactly the same thing right? the only difference is if you call the property with "isSmthg" or just "smthg"?

Comment: yes. See also this: [Naming conventions for BOOL Obj-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806900/naming-conventions-for-bool-obj-c-2-properties)