# What is the standard Objective-C BOOL getter convention?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, naming-conventions

I know that `@property (nonatomic, getter=isWhatever) BOOL whatever;` is the standard way to declare `BOOL` properties in Objective-C nowadays (as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/806900/2546659)).

But what is the preferred way to access this property? It's my understanding that for setters and non-`BOOL` properties, dot notation is preferred over `[someObject someProperty]`, but wouldn't this make defining a custom getter name superfluous?

To reiterate, I'm specifically interested in what the getter convention is: my understanding says `self.whatever`, which would render `[self isWhatever]` unused and `getter=isWhatever` pointless, which seems contradictory.

Is it an unintended side effect of the language's evolution over time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choosing a better name for the boolean than "whatever" would give a better idea. Example: `character` vs `isCharacter`. `self.isCharacter` seems fine and arguably better than `self.character`.

It would seem that using the "dot notation" does not change the boolean "is" prefix convention.

Comment: I agree that `self.isCharacter` looks better, but isn't it discouraged to use dot notation to conflate with method names?

Ahhhhhh maybe `BOOL`s are the exception to this.

Comment: dot-notation should not be used with methods that cause side-effects. Using it with `count` or `length` methods is OK and even supported by Xcode auto-completion. Basically use it with methods that would otherwise be properties. The bottom line: Write code to be easily understandable.

Comment: So what if the `BOOL` setter has a side effect, similar to `didSet` property observers in Swift? And what if those side effects are not meant to be known in its public API?

Comment: Any property can have an observer but that does not really count as a side-effect or action. An example of a method with no arguments  that has an action is `start` on `NSURLConnecton` and thus should not be used with dot-notation. But if you would rather not use the dot-syntax you don't have to.

Comment: I had to think about it for a while, but since the purpose of dot notation is to invoke accessor methods, this definitely makes the most sense to me!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO dot syntax should always be used for properties and bracket syntax for methods (you should NEVER call a property (getter/setter) method) and "is" should prefix all BOOL properties (NOT just the getter). The proper syntax for your property would then be myObj.isWhatever.

Comment: I agree that there should be a clear distinction between properties and methods, but using "is" for *everything* goes against [Apple's recommendations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html).

Comment: Andrew is correct: Nouns & verbs: as-is; adjectives: the property name omits the “is” prefix but specifies the conventional name for the get accessor. (Andrew comment +1).