# Using the word 'set' on a class's property in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm learning iOS development and choose to move back and forth between Objective-C and Swift to notice differences or similarities.  While working through a tutorial in Objective-C, I noticed that Xcode autocomplete feature allows my code from the tutorial which reads:

```
taskField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:fieldFrame];
    [taskField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [taskField setPlaceholder:@"Type a task, tap Insert"];
```

I decided to lookup UITextField reference pages, change the reference page's language to Objective-C, and noticed that the properties don't generally use the pre-text 'set'.  Should the pre-text 'set' be used at all times for properties when writing in Objective-C?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Naming conventions for BOOL Obj-C 2 properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806900/naming-conventions-for-bool-obj-c-2-properties)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is that the following two lines are equivalent in this case:

```
taskField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
[taskField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
```

`set` is the standard prefix on a "setter" *method*-- this can be a little confusing if you're new to ObjC. The actual property *name* here is e.g. `borderStyle`, and if you use the dot syntax setter, you would write `taskField.borderStyle = ...`. If you invoke the setter with the message notation (brackets), then you use the setBorderStyle: explicitly.

Here's the history that explains this: Way back (10+ years ago anyway), ObjC did not have any declared, formal properties, and did not have "dot" syntax for accessing them. You'd create a "private" instance variable, and then you would write the idiomatic getters and setters for that value. By convention, the setter was prefixed with "set" and the getter had no prefix (it was just the "property name"). All access to that value, both get and set, was done with bracket notation. Fast forward through some intermediate evolution, and now the handy `@property` declaration will do a lot of automatic synthesis for you of *all* the once-cumbersome boilerplate code you used to have to write. The method synthesis naming rules are automatic and follow the earlier conventions. Most documentation today will demonstrate property access using dot notation, but the getter and setter methods are autogenerated, and are still available for direct use.

So in short, most often by convention, you will now write `taskField.borderStyle = ...`, but you can also call `[taskField setBorderStyle:...]`. The former essentially invokes the latter method, and both are semantically the same.

Comment: I really appreciate your continuous edits to improve your theory and the background information added more context which is extremely helpful to my own personal learning process.

Answer (score 1):

You access or set an object’s properties via accessor methods:

```
NSString *firstName = [somePerson       firstName];
[somePerson setFirstName:@"Johnny"];
```

By default, these accessor methods are synthesized automatically for you by the compiler, so you don’t need to do anything other than declare the property using @property in the class interface.

The synthesized methods follow specific naming conventions:

The method used to access the value (the getter method) has the same name as the property.
The getter method for a property called firstName will also be called firstName.

The method used to set the value (the setter method) starts with the word “set” and then uses the capitalized property name.
The setter method for a property called firstName will be called setFirstName:.

If you don’t want to allow a property to be changed via a setter method, you can add an attribute to a property declaration to specify that it should be readonly:

```
@property (readonly) NSString *fullName;
```

For details see this link [Use Accessor Methods to Get or Set Property Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html)